# How can I use cheerio web scraper as an agent tool in Flowise?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am developing a small project on Flowise and I need to use Cheerio web scraper as a tool for agent. How can I do this? Or is there any way or tool to do in python langchain app when I give the website url, it scraps and give me the all text?

Answer (score 0):

Check this flowise documentation, it is easy to setup.
https://docs.flowiseai.com/use-cases/web-scrape-qna

You must install last version of flowise

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).